# Running a loop with if else condition applied to subsets of a data frame (or to the complete data frame)

Tags: r

I have the following problem: I need to run each subset of a dataframe creating new entries for the variable **role** depending on 2 conditions: the matching between the names of witnesses and household dwellers.

The dataframe (df) is as follows: I have 10 variables (**ID**, **birth_year**, last name –**Name2nd**-, role in the household -**role**-, household -**hh**-, first name –**Name1st**-, first name of witness1 - **name1stW1**-, last name of witness1 – **name2ndW1**-, **relation** with ID and relation with ID’s spouse –**relation2**-).

The whole table is subsetted by the **hh** variable, gathering all the IDs under the same household. The last four variables show the name of the first witness in the marriage of the ID, as well as their relation to that ID -**relation**- and to their spouse –**relation2**-. For instance, in my example bellow, ID 1 is *Albert Snijders* whose wedding witness is *Kornelis Marteen*. *Kornelis Marteen* is his brother (**relation**) and brother in law of the spouse (**relation2**).

Now here, as *Kornelis Marteen* is also living in the same household as ID 1 and we know the relation between ID 1 and 2, I need to change the value of the variable **role** from NA to “brother-brother in law” (in other words, for the value of the combination of the two relations: **relation**-**relation2**).

```
ID  birth_year    Name2nd           role        hh    Name1st name2ndW1 name1stW1 relation relation2
1    1877        Snijders    HeadOfHousehold     1     Albert    Marteen   Kornelis  brother brother-in-law
2    1885        Marteen     NA                  1     Kornelis  NA        NA         NA     NA
3    1897        Snijders    NA                  1     Marja     NA        NA         NA     NA
4    1892        Zelstra     NA                  1     Inge      NA        NA         NA     NA
5    1878        Kuipers     HeadOfHousehold     2     Hans      Snijders  Marja      friend friend
6    1870        Marteen     NA                  2     Joris     Marteen   Joris      NA     NA    
7    1897        Wals        NA                  2     Michel    NA        NA         NA     NA
8    1900        Venstra     NA                  2     Joop      NA        NA         NA     NA
9    1900        Lippe       HeadOfHousehold     3     Jaap      NA        NA         NA     NA
10   1905        Flachs      NA                  3     Klaas     Alb       Kuipers    NA     NA
11   1920        Lippe       NA                  3     Mathias   NA        NA         NA     NA
12   1922        Lippe       NA                  3     Waltfried Flachs    Klaas    cousin   cousin
```

You can get the table this way:

```
A <- read.table(header=T, text="ID  birth_year    Name2nd           role             hh    Name1st name2ndW1 name1stW1 relation relation2
                                1    1877        Snijders    HeadOfHousehold          1     Albert    Marteen   Kornelis  brother brother-in-law
                                2    1885        Marteen     NA                       1     Kornelis  NA        NA         NA     NA
                                3    1897        Snijders    NA                       1     Marja     NA        NA         NA     NA
                                4    1892        Zelstra     NA                       1     Inge      NA        NA         NA     NA
                                5    1878        Kuipers     HeadOfHousehold          2     Hans      Snijders  Marja      friend friend
                                6    1870        Marteen     NA                       2     Joris     Marteen   Joris      NA     NA    
                                7    1897        Wals        NA                       2     Michel    NA        NA         NA     NA
                                8    1900        Venstra     NA                       2     Joop      NA        NA         NA     NA
                                9    1900        Lippe       HeadOfHousehold          3     Jaap      NA        NA         NA     NA
                                10   1905        Flachs      NA                       3     Klaas     Kuipers   Alb        NA     NA
                                11   1920        Lippe       NA                       3     Mathias   NA        NA         NA     NA
                                12   1922        Lippe       NA                       3     Waltfried Flachs    Klaas  cousin  cousin  "    
                  , as.is = T)
```

Once here, I have two questions. What I was trying to do is to cluster by household (hh) and if any member of the household happens to also be a witness of any household member's marriage, then modify the value of their role (to those appearing in the variables of relation).

I thought of ddply:

df <- ddply(df,.(hh),transform,role = ifelse( (name2ndW1==Name2nd & name1stW1==Name1st),paste(relatie-relatie2),NA))

But this is not working. I don't get any changes in "role". This is my main concern.

My second question -not so important- is for the case I decided no to perform this **ifelse** test per subset (hh), but for the whole data set. Is there any similar code to the above like

df <- ddply(df,.(),transform,role = ifelse( (name2ndW1==Name2nd & name1stW1==Name1st),paste(relatie-relatie2),NA))

without the grouping variables

My expected outcome would be:

```
ID  birth_year    Name2nd           role             hh    Name1st name2ndW1 name1stW1 relation relation2
1    1877        Snijders    HeadOfHousehold          1     Albert    Marteen   Kornelis  brother brother-in-law
2    1885        Marteen     brother-brother-in-law   1     Kornelis  NA        NA         NA     NA
3    1897        Snijders    NA                       1     Marja     NA        NA         NA     NA
4    1892        Zelstra     NA                       1     Inge      NA        NA         NA     NA
5    1878        Kuipers     HeadOfHousehold          2     Hans      Snijders  Marja      friend friend
6    1870        Marteen     NA                       2     Joris     Marteen   Joris      NA     NA    
7    1897        Wals        NA                       2     Michel    NA        NA         NA     NA
8    1900        Venstra     NA                       2     Joop      NA        NA         NA     NA      
9    1900        Lippe       HeadOfHousehold          3     Jaap      NA        NA         NA     NA
10   1905        Flachs      cousin-cousin            3     Klaas     Kuipers   Alb        NA     NA
11   1920        Lippe       NA                       3     Mathias   NA        NA         NA     NA
12   1922        Lippe       NA                       3     Waltfried Flachs    Klaas    cousin  cousin
```

Any tips are welcome, and thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, using package `dplyr` rather than `plyr`. The trick is to join the table with a copy of itself, mapping the person name to the witness name. To make it more clear I created `df_witness`, which is a copy (subsetted) of `A` with renamed fields

```
library(dplyr)
df_witness = A %>%
  select(hh, Name1st=name1stW1, Name2nd=name2ndW1, i_rel=relation, i_rel2=relation2) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Name2nd))

A %>% 
  left_join(
    df_witness, 
    by = c("hh", "Name1st", "Name2nd")
    ) %>% 
  mutate(role = if_else(!is.na(role), role, paste0(i_rel,"-",i_rel2))) %>% 
  select(-i_rel, -i_rel2)
```

If you want to search the witness within the whole dataset rather than only within the household, you can join `by = c("Name1st", "Name2nd")` (and drop variable `hh` from `df_witness`)